# Swap not mounted at boot (UUID is correct)

Tags: swap, systemd

I can't get swap to mount automatically at boot.
Ubuntu 16.04.

I've read many articles/forums, generally everyone points to an incorrect UUID.  My UUID is 100% correct.  I have also tried mounting via /dev/sdc1 rather than UUID, it makes no difference.

journalctl indicates the swap partition is identified and mounted, but free shows it isn't.

```
root@openflixr:~# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       10232716     1363616     7179204       24664     1689896     8455264
Swap:             0           0           0

root@openflixr:~# lsblk -fm
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT     NAME    SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb                                                                     sdb      52G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1 ext3         a3ea80ea-9304-44b5-b780-2cc66e56a75e /mnt/downloads └─sdb1   52G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0                                                                     sr0    1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
sdc                                                                     sdc      16G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdc1 swap         4c778935-85d6-4399-8083-43906ba1872f                └─sdc1   16G root  disk  brw-rw----
sda                                                                     sda     100G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda1 ext4         8f023205-2b57-4f4d-80d3-b557a3f2aa58 /              └─sda1   96G root  disk  brw-rw----

root@openflixr:~# journalctl | grep -i swap
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr systemd[1]: Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/4c778935-85d6-4399-8083-43906ba1872f...
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: Adding 16771068k swap on /dev/sdc1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:16771068k FS
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr systemd[1]: Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/4c778935-85d6-4399-8083-43906ba1872f.
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.

root@openflixr:~# journalctl | grep sdc
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] 33554432 512-byte logical blocks: (17.2 GB/16.0 GiB)
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 61 00 00 00
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Cache data unavailable
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel:  sdc: sdc1
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: sd 2:0:2:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr kernel: Adding 16771068k swap on /dev/sdc1.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:16771068k FS

root@openflixr:~# mount -va
/                        : ignored
/mnt/downloads           : already mounted
swap                     : ignored

root@openflixr:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8f023205-2b57-4f4d-80d3-b557a3f2aa58 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sdb1       /mnt/downloads  ext3    defaults        0       0
UUID=4c778935-85d6-4399-8083-43906ba1872f       none    swap    sw      0       0

root@openflixr:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb623abb1

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 33544191 33542144  16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

root@openflixr:~# systemctl status swap.target
● swap.target - Swap
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/swap.target; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active since Sat 2018-09-22 11:43:14 NZST; 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Sep 22 11:43:14 openflixr systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
```

But that appears to be incorrect:

```
root@openflixr:~# systemctl --type swap
0 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.

root@openflixr:~# systemctl --type swap --all
UNIT                                         LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4c778935\x2d85d6\x2d4399\x2d8083\x2d43906ba1872f.swap loaded inactive dead /dev/disk/by-uui

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
```

As soon as I do anything related to swap, it shows fine.

```
root@openflixr:~# swapon -va
swapon /dev/sdc1
swapon: /dev/sdc1: found swap signature: version 1d, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /dev/sdc1: pagesize=4096, swapsize=17173577728, devsize=17173577728

root@openflixr:~# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       10232728     1450820     7083756       24664     1698152     8366116
Swap:      16771068           0    16771068
```

I've wiped and recreated the partition table of the disk, I originally created it as GPT but I understand there may be issues with swap on GPT, so it's now MS-DOS.

I get the feeling this is something to do with systemd versus the 'old' way of doing swap, but I've tried so many things without success.

I've now run out of google results to try, so any help is very much appreciated.

Edit:
Updated /etc/fstab to use mountpoint 'none' instead of 'swap' - no change.

Edit:
The issue seems centred around this systemctl stuff:

```
root@openflixr:~# systemctl --type swap --all
UNIT                                         LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB  DESCRIPTION
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4c778935\x2d85d6\x2d4399\x2d8083\x2d43906ba1872f.swap loaded inactive dead /dev/disk/by-uui

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

1 loaded units listed.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.

root@openflixr:~# systemctl start swap.target

root@openflixr:~# systemctl --type swap --all
UNIT                                         LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
dev-disk-by\x2dpath-pci\x2d0000:03:00.0\x2dsas\x2dphy2\x2dlun\x2d0\x2dpart1.swap loaded active active /dev/disk
dev-disk-by\x2duuid-4c778935\x2d85d6\x2d4399\x2d8083\x2d43906ba1872f.swap loaded active active /dev/disk/by-uui
dev-sdc1.swap                                loaded active active /dev/sdc1

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

3 loaded units listed.
```

I don't get it - the swap.target unit for systemctl is enabled and as per above, the journalctl output shows that the swap is being found and activated.

- Jay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh wow. Found the issue:

```
root@openflixr:/etc# cat rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
echo "32768 61000" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
swapoff -a  <------------------------------------------------- doh
echo noop >/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo 1 >/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run
echo 1000 >/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs
```

This is what happens when you don't build the machine.
Always check the basics, folks.

I'll show myself out.